# Audit trail for log in and logout in SharePoint FBA Based site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing

I have a `Forms Based Authentication` site in `SharePoint 2010` in which I have a custom login webpart through which it enables the user to log in.

Now I want to maintain the audit trial record for `login`, `log out`, `reset password`, `change password` and unsuccessful number of login attempts. I'm using `aspnetmembership` `SQL Server Database` for storing the registration details.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to develop the auditing solution. An example of an auditing solution is outlined [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/tracking-user-activity.aspx), but what you'll want to do is add custom code to pages which involve these actions (such as login, logout, change password pages).